# Embed Python HTTP server into C program as RPC server?

Tags: c++, python, c, http, embedded

I have a program written in C++ with a web interface to for the purpose of RPC.  I can call `http://localhost/ListVariables` or `http://localhost/RunFunction?var=1` and have the C code execute ListVariables or RunFunction.  It works, but I'd rather not have to manage the web server in C/C++ when there are so many good Python web servers out there.

What I'm imagining is having the C program call into Python to start a web server on another thread (i.e. Tornado), return to C and then continue chugging along doing calculations.  Then when the Python server receives a request on `http://localhost/ListVariables`, it calls *back* into C and executes ListVariables on the already running process.

```
C -----> processing -----------> processing ------------> RPC: FuncA -------->
 |                                                        ^        |
  \---> Python Web Server ---------- Request for: FuncA --/   ...   \-------->
                                     ^
  browser: http://localhost/FuncA ---/
```

The project has the unfortunate caveat that the program must be started from C to begin with.  After doing some research this seems to be a bit of a border case, since Python-->C and C-->Python can be done with Cython.  However, I can't find many resources on C-->Python-->C, as most of the examples I've found describe linking to libraries and not to already-running processes.  Is it possible to have Python call back into a running C program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolutely. [Create a "fake" module](http://docs.python.org/extending/extending.html) in the C program injected into `sys.modules` that the Python code can import and access as it would any other module.

Comment: Thanks.  Now I just have to figure out how to do this with Cython, since from what I've read it abstracts a lot of the PythonC API.

Answer (score 0):

I personally really like the boost::python library for embedded python into c++ and dealing with data binding and callbacks between the two. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/python/doc/

That being said, what you're proposing sounds like a bit of a PITA. I've personally have had a lot of success using http://libevent.org/ to fulfill my embedded webserver needs. It handles all of the http server stuff for you, all you need to do is give it the urls you want to handle and a callback, put the `event_base_loop` somewhere in your main loop (or in it's own thread if you'd rather), and away you go. That to me seems like it might be a lot easier than embedding python and dealing with passing data and data structures between the two.

Comment: Since I'm already using boost, this may make sense so I'll look into it.  I'm currently using Mongoose (the web server, not the DB), so switching to libevent wouldn't buy me much; I'm looking to python for the simplicity.